# Is there any example/demo about OCR by using TF Lite?

Tags: mobile, ocr, tensorflow-lite

I see that the OCR is in the  TFLite usage list in the TFDevSummit2019.  Is there any example/demo  about OCR by using TF Lite?

Description: I want to train an OCR model small enough based on deeplearning, and convert it to tflite format, then deploy it to a mobile phone. I worked for couple of days, still can not get any idea to get an OCR model of tflite format.

(OCR in the "Image" part,  HOPE to get some solutions~~)
[TFDevSummit2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3USic.jpg)

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem?
I was looking for a trained model to use it with TF Lite, and I stumbled upon your question...

Comment: Have you see the example [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/optical_character_recognition/overview)